# Conditional formatting: same query -> different charts -> different measures

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I have built a query with a bunch of measures.
I am visualising each measure as a separate bar chart.
Each chart needs to have its' own conditional formatting.
Unable to achieve it so far - as soon as I set conditional formatting for Chart1 (Measure 1), then move on to Chart2 (Measure2), it straight away cancels the formatting for Chart1 - resets it to default.

As a solution now I duplicated the charts, however, that created new queries.

Any idea how I could use the same query, on different charts, and apply different conditional formatting for each measure on different charts?

[image]

Thank you!